# Jmeter showing responce message as found

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

When i run this Url using JMETER load testing tool URL http://thebus.in/b2c/booking.aspx?sourceid=1128&destinationid=198&doj=15/october/2014&dor=30/october/2014&Id=0&seats=E3&board=188&noreturn=true

In Responce data under view results tree, when i run the above URL the message is displayed as

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Object Moved</title>
</head>
</body>
<h2>object moved to</h2>
<a href="/Home.aspx"here>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and in sampler result responce code is displayed in green, responce message is found

I want to know why Jmeter is showing the result so?

Comment: You have not given enough information to answer this properly.  What settings are you using for HTTP request (follow rediects? keep-alive?)? What other elements do you include in your test plan? (cookie manager? request defaults?)
I can only get similar response if i set to not follow redirects. The first response back is then the redirection (rc 302). This is shown in green as it is not an error, but it is not 200 (OK).
What do you expect to get as a response?

Answer (score 0):

Charan,

If the URL you are hitting is getting redirected, then you will get 302 http response code and the above 'Object Moved to' message.

You can just try this in a normal browser.

http://thebus.in/b2c/booking.aspx?sourceid=1128&destinationid=198&doj=15/october/2014&dor=30/october/2014&Id=0&seats=E3&board=188&noreturn=true

When i tried to access the above URL, I was redirected to below page.

http://thebus.in/Home.aspx

So, in your script, do you login? If yes, do you have HTTP Cookie manager?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set your  HTTP Request sampler to "not follow redirects".  Then, you wont see that redirected page any longer.  Then, I would also recommend adding an Assertion step as a substep within the HTTP Request sampler.